# How do I register DbContext EF Core in ServiceStack Core?

Tags: entity-framework, servicestack, inversion-of-control, dbcontext

With EF Core, DbContext is registered as Scoped by EF service extension. This is desirable because DbContext is not thread-safe and therefore it should be created per request.

ServiceStack IOC treats any Scoped registration in Startup as singleton, which contradicts with the point above.

One possible solution is to not use EF Core's service extension, but that seems to bring a lot of boilerplate code and reduce maintainability. Is there any better way?

--

UPDATE

I'd like to provide sample code for clarity

I added a private Guid to the DbContext class so that I can tell whether we have the new instance.

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly Guid _instance;

    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { 
        _instance = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

With .NET Core MVC, the controller code looks like

```
public class BlogsController : Controller
{
    private readonly BloggingContext _context;

    public BlogsController(BloggingContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // skip for readability
}
```

For each request hitting the controller, the _instance inside BloggingContext returns an unique value. However, when using within a ServiceStack service, _instance always returns the same value.

```
public class BlogService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    private readonly BloggingContext _context;

    public BlogService(BloggingContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // skip for readability
}
```

This behaviour is consistent with ServiceStack documentation about [.NET Core Container Adapter](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-container-adapter) that scoped dependencies registered in .NET Core Startup is singleton within ServiceStack. However, it is not desirable because we want DbContext to be created per request.

My solution is that I move the DbContext registration into AppHost code as below

```c#
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.AddScoped(c => 
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    });     
}
```

This code works as I expect. Every instance of BloggingContext injected into my BlogService is now unique. However, I find myself unable to use any service collection extension which is very handy in .Net Core Startup anymore. For example, I want to use [Entity Framework Unit Of Work](https://github.com/arch/UnitOfWork) and I couldn't call

```c#
services
    .AddUnitOfWork<BloggingContext>();
```

Instead, I have to wire up all dependencies of that library myself like

```c#
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.AddScoped(c => 
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    });     
    container.AddScoped<IRepositoryFactory, UnitOfWork<BloggingContext>>();
    container.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork<BloggingContext>>();
    container.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork<BloggingContext>, UnitOfWork<BloggingContext>>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to register it in [.NET Core's IOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection) like any .NET Core App:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => 
       options.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db"));
}
```

Then reference like a normal dependency in your ServiceStack Services:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
     public BloggingContext BloggingContext { get; set; }
}
```

Which uses [ServiceStack's .NET Core Container Adapter](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-container-adapter) to resolve any dependencies not in ServiceStack's IOC, in .NET Core's IOC.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clearer. What you said is correct but I don't think it addressed my question. But thanks a lot for answering and for your great work. I love ServiceStack with a passion.

Comment: Demis, any updates on this based on the edit? ie. how to use per-request scoped constructor/property injection in SS service classes when those dependencies are registered in the asp.net core container?

Comment: @Tyson Have a look at the [ASP.NET Core IServiceProvider APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/ioc#aspnet-core-iserviceprovider-apis) in v5.5+ for how to access ASP.NET Core scoped dependencies.

Comment: thanks, but I'd prefer for normal constructor injection to work though, not manually resolve off of the Request within the service method.
But nm, I found this:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/adef34a31f4b500237a76ddff943766d6c13245c
ie. I just had to add `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`
Might be worth updating your docs here: https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-container-adapter
Or is there a particular reason you don't publish this behaviour? Anything I should be aware of?

Comment: @Tyson ASP.NET Core’s HttpContextAccessor has [been disabled by default for performance reasons](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/190#issue-159298966)